# Want to share website content on facebook

Tags: php, facebook, share

I got a problem in facebook share: I want to post Content, title, URL on facebook in php but i am unable to post all things except  than URL.

I have a link to share on facebook.

```
   <a onClick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=
     <?=$forum_list['subject']; ?>&amp;p[summary]=
     <?= $forum_list['content'] ?>&amp;p[url]=
     <?php echo $url; ?>&amp;p[images][0]=
     <?php //$image;?>','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');
       " href="javascript: void(0)">
     <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>img/face.png" />
   </a>
```

Comment: How to share content of my website on facebook.Check   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761019/how-to-share-content-of-my-website-on-facebook

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--use this meta tag -->

    <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $deal['deal_title'] ;?>" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://domain.com/img/<?php echo $deal['deal_image']; ?>" />
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="620" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="541" />

<!-- Put this ancor tag in your body -->
<a onclick="fb_Share();" title=" Facebook - Share And Earn"><img src="img/fb-earn.gif" alt=" Facebook - Share And Earn" width="299" height="60"></a>
<!-- use this Javascript -->

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
   <script>
     function fb_Share(){
         FB.init({ 
            appId:'apID', cookie:true, 
            status:true, xfbml:true 
         });

         FB.ui({ method: 'feed',
                link: document.URL,
            },
            function(response) {
        if (response && !response.error_code) 
          {
               // you action    
          } 
       else 
           {
              alert(response);
          }
      }

            );
      }

      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`sharer.php` only takes the URL as parameter, it reads the Open Graph tags directly from the URL and you can't dynamically set anything (anymore).

More information about the specific Open Graph tags: http://ogp.me/